# Animação Jquery para mudar texto de uma div

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, animação

Tenho um layout responsivo e um dos elementos de uma ROW é um texto/parágrafo que quero que fique trocando a cada 5 segundos por outro paragrafo, por exemplo.

Tenho a seguinte função para mover o conteúdo da div

```
    function moverTexto(){

        $('#descricao').animate({left:"-800" },1000)

    }
```

no main eu tenho:

```
    <section id="meio"> 

        <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">


                            <div id = "descricao" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6" >

                                 <p> <strong style="font-size: 50px; ">SER</strong> bla bla bla: <strong style="color:#c8270a;font-weight:800;"> SABEDORIA </strong>,<strong style="color:#ecb213;font-weight:800;"> EMPATIA </strong> e <strong style="color:#0c5f93;font-weight:800;"> RESPEITO </strong>.

                                <p> bla bla bla  </p>  

                                <p> bla bla bla </p>

                                <p> bla bla bla </p>



                            </div>


                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6" >
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="img/arte.jpg">
                            </div>



                    </div>
```

Gostaria que aparece um elemento de parágrafo por vez na div descricao a cada X segundos, tipo rotacionando do primeiro ao último, depois volta para o primeiro. E isso ocorre ao lado da foto que está na outra div.

Comment: Cinthia sem seu código não tem como te responder. Edite sua pergunta e coloque o que vc já tem ai de HTML/CSS pelo menos, tb diga se já usa ou pretende usar jQuery no projeto ou JS. Da forma como perguntou não da para te responder...

Comment: Editei, Hugo. Poderia me ajudar? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, CSS tb é matemática! Mas não se assuste, vou explicar os detalhes. 
Segundo, não precisa de JS ou jQuery...

Como vc comentou, vamos ter 5 elementos onde cada 1 fica 5s na tela. Logo teremos 5x5 = 25, então nossa animação tem que ter 25 segundos.

Agora vamos pegar nossa animação que vai de 0 a 100% e dividir por 5, pois são 5 intervalos de 5s, isso nos diz que cada 20% da animação corresponde a 5s.

Isso significa que de 0 a 20% meu elemento fica na tela, completando 5s, depois ele passa o resto da animação oculto. Assim a cada 5s aparece o elemento seguinte.

A propriedade `animation-delay` vai evitar que a animação dos elementos comecem ao mesmo tempo. Então a cada elemento vc tem que aumentar 5s no `delay`, o segundo elemento tem `delay` de 5s, terceiro tem `delay` de 10s, o quarto 15s etc...

Assim vc consegue o resultado desejado. Execute o código abaixo para ver
*Deixei os comments no código*

```css
.texto {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fader 25s infinite;
}
/* cada texto tem um delay de 5 + o valor do delay anterior, meno o primeiro */
.a {
    animation-delay: 0s;    
}
.b {
    animation-delay: 5s;
}
.c {
    animation-delay: 10s;
}
.d {
    animation-delay: 15s;
}
.e {
    animation-delay: 20s;
}

/* Animação acontece apenas entre 0 e 20%, pois são 5 elementos */
@keyframes fader {
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.anima {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<section id="meio">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div id="descricao" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">

                <p> <strong style="font-size: 50px; margin-botton:100px;">
                    SER</strong> bla bla bla: <strong style="color:#c8270a;font-weight:800;">
                        SABEDORIA </strong>,<strong style="color:#ecb213;font-weight:800;"> EMPATIA </strong> e
                    <strong style="color:#0c5f93;font-weight:800;"> RESPEITO </strong>
                </p>

                  <div class="anima">
                      <p class="texto a">Texto item 1</p>
                      <p class="texto b">Texto item 2</p>
                      <p class="texto c">Texto item 3</p>
                      <p class="texto d">Texto item 4</p>
                      <p class="texto e">Texto item 5</p>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, Hugo. Funcionou perfeitamente. Mas depois de aparecer o último elemento de parágrafo, não aparece mais nada. A ideia é que voltasse a apresentar o conteúdo do início. E muito obrigada por explicar detalhadamente.

Comment: Cinthia aqui está funcionando normalmente! Repare que eu deixei a animação para ficar infinita! `animation: fader 25s infinite;` Vc inclusive pode verificar aqui mesmo no site que ela faz o loop perfeitamente, depois do item 5 ela volta para o primeiro... https://imgur.com/20nvrfq

Comment: Deu certo mesmo, Hugo. Muito obrigada.

Comment: @Cinthia que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes mesmo já tendo sido resolvidas.